# How do I access data from a Grails Filter?

Tags: grails, groovy

OK, I have a Grails filter that looks like this:

```
after = { model ->
    modifyDataFromController(model)
}
```

I want to modify the data getting rendered from the controller like this:

```
def myAction = {
    def myJson = getJson() // this returns JSON  
    render(contentType:"application/json", text:myJson)
}
```

So, is there a way for me to access myJson via the model object?  If not, how am I supposed to access the data from the controller?  Please be very specific, and don't assume I know what you're talking about. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just to clarify, why do you need a filter? why not modify the data in the controller itself?

Answer (score 0):

The `model` property in the filter is null, because

```
render(contentType:"application/json", text:myJson)
```

write `myJson` directly into response. I can not find a solution to access response content within a filter method, if anybody has elegant way to do it please kindly post the solution here.

At this moment what I can figure out is to modify that `render` to something like this:

```
render(template:'blankTemplate', model:[data:myJson])
```

where `blankTemplate` refers to a blank gsp file, namely _blankTemplate.gsp. Then in the filter you can access the json data and render it afterwards:

```
after = { model ->
    modifyDataFromController(model.data)
    render(contentType:"application/json", text:model.data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of rendering blank template you could just return the model itself

Following can be the last line of your action.

`[data:myJson]`